# how to upload image to backblaze using hapijs

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I am trying to upload image to backblaze-b2 using hapi.js. I am using a plugin called easy-backblaze but while using it I need to mention the path of the file. But While importing the file using Hapijs I am not able to understand how to get that path.

This is the Code I have written and here in b2.uploadFile I need to mention the path of the file on local Drive:

var B2 = require('easy-backblaze');

```
var b2 = new B2('accountId', 'applicationKey');

b2.uploadFile('C:/Users/Lovika/Desktop/addDriver.png', {
    name: 'addDriver.png', // Optional, renames file
    bucket: 'testBucket', // Optional, defaults to first bucket
}, function(err, res) {
    console.log('Done!', err, res);
});
```

Do I need to upload the file to the server first and then to backblaze or Is there any way to upload the file directly to backblaze